# assertRedirectedToRoute giving error in php unit

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

After running  PHPunit i got an error at

```
$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('posts.index'); // line 50
$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('posts.index', ['flash']);  //line 84
```

1)

```
PostsControllerTest::testStore
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@


/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:245
/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:260
/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/app/tests/controllers/PostsControllerTest.php:50
```

2)

```
PostsControllerTest::testStoreSuccess
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
-- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@


/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:245
/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:260
/usr/share/nginx/www/laravelphpunitest/app/tests/controllers/PostsControllerTest.php:84
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the docs

public void assertRedirectedToRoute(string $name, array $parameters = array(), array $with = array())

Assert whether the client was redirected to a given route.
Parameters
string  $name
array   $parameters 
array   $with

So you should pass the "with" in the assertRedirectedToRoute third argument like:

```
$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('posts.index', [] ,['flash']);
```

hope it helps.